# Prove that when $M$ moves in $d$ then $KI$ passes through a fixed point.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

A circle $\mathcal{O}$ is centered at point $O$, and there's a line $d$ which doesn't have common point with $\mathcal{O}$. Let point $H$ be the projection of $O$ on $d$.

Consider a point $M$ that moves along $d$. Let $\overline{MA}$ and $\overline{MB}$ tangent with $\mathcal{O}$ at points $A$ and $B$ respectively. The points $K$ and $I$ are the projections of $H$ on $\overleftrightarrow{MA}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{MB}$ respectively.

> Prove that when $M$ moves along $d$, the extended line $\overleftrightarrow{KI}$ passes through a fixed point.

I think the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{KI}$ and $\overline{OH}$ is the fixed point, but I do not know how to prove it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It's true that the intersection $X$ of $KI$ and $OH$ is the fixed point, but I'm having troubles proving that. Another fact that's true is that $X$ lies on the radical axis of $(O,R)$ and circle $MNKI$, but I can't prove this one either.

Comment: Proving the fact mentioned in the second sentence is enough, as then $XH$ is a segment of a fixed distance (it lies on $OH$ which has fixed direction) and hence $X$ is fixed.